# QuartzScheduler injection in JBoss AS 6

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, quartz-scheduler, java-ee-6

How can i inject QuartzScheduler service into my Stateless bean on JBoss AS 6 ? 
Quartz service does start during JBoss AS 6 startup

```
00:58:38,025 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.3) 'JBossQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

00:58:38,026 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'JBossQuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally opened InputStream.
00:58:38,026 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.3
```

i have tried this:

```
@Stateless(name="myEnterpriseScheduler")
public class MyEnterpriseScheduler {
    @Resource(name="JBossQuartzScheduler")
    Scheduler scheduler;


}
```

But then i get the following exception:

```
00:58:40,583 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=jboss.jacc:id="vfs:///Users/merodach/Downloads/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EnterpriseSchedular-ear.ear",service=jacc state=Described mode=Manual requiredState=Configured: java.lang.Error: Error in the server: mismatch between expected constructor arguments and supplied arguments.
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.handleInstantiateExceptions(MBeanServerImpl.java:1317) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:1249) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:288) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.installPlainMBean(ServiceCreator.java:217) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:133) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:73) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:46) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:257) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:93) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_22]
```

any idea?

UPDATE: Here is my use case:
i want to create the cron triggers dynamically which are submitted from other processes using cron expressions in a distributed environment, not with annotations statically. these requests are caught by a RESTful service, and saved into the database, after the triggers with given expressions are activated. These cron triggers schedule tasks which are also sent by clients/applications and saved in database.

Comment: I'm not even sure that's supposed to work - at least I cannot find JBoss docs that suggest it should.

Comment: I'm also interested in this issue, but I get a different exception: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Neither any mapped-name/lookup/jndi-name specified nor any ResourceProvider could process resource-env-ref named env/JBossQuartzScheduler of type org.quartz.Scheduler`

Answer (score 1):

**How about this post?** https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureAQuartzService

Comment: thanks. it's my current solution which's on production system.

Answer (score 0):

Despite extensive search in the Internet and several tests I didn't find a solution. I'm wondering why nobody else wants to have access to the Quartz-Scheduler inside JBoss.

I want to share a code snippet which is not the solution and not even a workaround, but it fit's my needs because I want periodically check some states and dynamically create a new Job.

```
@ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "cronTrigger",
                              propertyValue = "0 * * * * ?")})  
public class MyCronWatchDog implements Job  
{  
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jex) throws JobExecutionException  
    {  
         System.out.println("Quartz job executed!!");
         Scheduler scheduler = jex.getScheduler();   
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to create the cron triggers dynamically which are submitted from other processes using cron expressions in a distributed environment, not with annotations statically. these requests are caught by a RESTful service, and saved into the database, after the triggers with given expressions activated.

Comment: This was only an example how to get a `Scheduler`, in my environment the execution times will permanently change. Perhaps we really don't need the `Scheduler` at all (that's why nobody knows hot to inject it). I created a new more generally question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161555

Answer (score 0):

Can not use EJB3 TimerService instead? Create a session bean with timer service and call its schedule method

```
@Stateless
public class MySchedule implements MyScheduleRemote
{
    @Resource TimerService timerService;
    public void schedule ( Date date , ...)
    {
        timerService.createTimer( date, ..);
    }
}
```