# How to dynamically add a Quartz Job in JBoss6

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler, jboss6.x

I'm using JBoss6 and want to dynamically create Quartz-Jobs. During the processing of the job the next start time will be defined (e.g. in 1, 5 or 10 hours).

I didn't find any solutions for this, it's even hard to get access to the `org.quartz.Scheduler` (see [QuartzScheduler injection in JBoss AS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943485)).

The next problem is the creation of new Jobs, I followed the tutorial http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson02.html:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;

// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
  JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
      .withIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
      .build();

  // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
  Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
      .withIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
      .startNow()
      .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
          .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
          .repeatForever())            
      .build();

  // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
  sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

But it seems the `org.quartz.JobBuilder` is not available for JBoss6. If i manually add the quartz-dependency have errors on startup (class loading issues). This artifacts are defined (without explicitly using Quartz):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbosssx-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbosssx</artifactId>
        </exclusion> 
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss 6 you can get at the Quartz scheduler using a factory class provided within the Quartz library.  This should be all you need:

```
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
```

We use this within a context listener at start up to dynamically schedule jobs.  HTH.

Comment: Also note, JBoss 6 will initialize the Quartz scheduler while booting the server instance; however, it then leaves the scheduler in standby mode.  Hence, the scheduler must be explicitly started before any of your scheduled triggers will fire.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Quartz is started in my environment automatically (I assume by have a `@ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar")` defined). My problem is that I don't know how to create new Jobs because `org.quartz.JobBuilder` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are following Quartz 2.0.x tutorial. Have you tried [Quartz 1.x tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson01)?

The version provided with JBoss 6 is Quartz 1.8.3, and there are significant [API changes in Quartz 2.x](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/new-in-quartz-2#api-changes).